# How to get the data-id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marionette

I am using backbone.marionette.js and I am able to populate value to the table, but I am facing a problem when trying to get the value for the selected row.

The following is my template:

```
<td><%= firstName %></td>
<td><%= lastName %></td>
<td><%= designation %></td>
<td>
  <a href="#" data-id='<%= userid %>'>
    <img src="assets/img/add.png"  id="add-puppet-button" alt="Add Row" />
  </a>
  <img src="assets/img/remove.png"  id="remove-puppet-button" alt="Remove Row"/>
</td>
```

The data is there in `data-id`. When I debug I see it is `undefined`. I try to get it the following way:

```
accordianView : function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var userid = $(e.currentTarget).data("userid");
  var puppet = new PuppetModel();
  puppet = PuppetTable.puppetCollection.get(userid);
  console.log("firstName : "+puppet.get("firstName"));
  console.log("lastName : "+puppet.get("lastName"));
  console.log("Designation : "+puppet.get("designation"));
}
```

What is the mistake I am making here? Please guide me to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

`var userid = $(e.currentTarget).data("userid");`

needs to be:

`var userid = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");`

Answer (score 0):

I'ts best to give the link an ID, or a class and then use the [data method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The only attributes available in your template by default are the ones defined on your model instance. It seems that `userid` doesn't belong to the model, so it will be undefined.

You can either attach the attribute to the model, or (the cleaner way) define a `serializeData` function in your view to enrich the data provided to the view: provide an object with all of the puppet instances attributes, and add the `userid`.

You can see an example of `serializeData` here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/common/views.js

The documentation relative to it is here: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#itemview-serializedata

Answer (score 0):

You are using a marionette item view.  You should not need to pull back data from the Dom.

Simply do

`var userid = this.model.get("userid");`

Backbone and marionette make it so you don't have to store data in the Dom.  You have a model for that.

While

`var userid = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");`

Would work. It is a bad pattern to be using with backbone.js

Comment: How would you do that if this is one item in a collection?

Comment: Itemviews know the particular model from that collection that they are bound to.

Comment: If you render a collection, then put a click event on each item, in the clickHandler there is no reference to the individual model?

Comment: If the click event is on a marionette itemview there is a reference see http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/22/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial-part-2/